# Getting this error whenever I try to use the Sound library in Processing

Tags: java, processing

```
Jun 06, 2023 5:43:01 PM com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice <init>
INFO: JSyn: default output latency set to 80 msec for Windows 11
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:484)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:115)
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.engine.SynthesisEngine$EngineThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine.read(byte[], int, int)" because "this.line" is null
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.engine.SynthesisEngine$EngineThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.RuntimeException: AudioInput stop attempted when no line created.
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.stop(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.engine.SynthesisEngine$EngineThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm appropriately using the Sound class in Processing Java with the following code, but I hear no sound and I get this error. How can I fix it?

```
import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile test;

void setup(){
  test = new SoundFile(this, "yikes.wav");
}

void draw(){
  test.play();
}
```

I tried restarting my PC, closing and opening Processing, checking my audio output, using different sound files, using different sound file types (.mp3, .wav), and more for a while but I can't find what the problem is. I still keep getting this error and am unable to continue.

Comment: Try moving 'test.play()' up into setup(), ie remove from draw().

Comment: There is no point in adding tags to the title of the question.